# How doing division each cell dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want calculate division of each cell by sum of each row. Actually there are many column not only `A` and `B`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1],
                 'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4]]})

sum_row = data.sum(axis=1)
```

Here is an example of what I expect.
[image]

Comment: `data.div(data.sum(1), axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1],
                 'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4]})

data['sum_row'] = data.sum(axis=1)

for col in list(data.columns.values):
    data[col + ' / Sum_Row'] = [data['A'].iloc[e] / data['sum_row'].iloc[e] for e in range(0, len(data['A']))]
```